# I need help in Regex,My requirement is the length of data should be either 12 or 14 but not 13

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need help in Regex,My requirement is the length of data should be either 12 or 14 but not 13.

Accordingly I created regex expression as ^[0-9]{12,14}$ .

It doesn't work Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the last two numbers optional with the `?` operator:

```
String regex = "^[0-9]{12}([0-9]{2})?$";
```

Also, `[0-9]` can be rewritten as `\\d`. This does the exact same thing:

```
String regex = "^\\d{12}(\\d{2})?$";
```

Comment: uhr... didn't notic that same as yours. up and remove mine.

Comment: ^(?:\d{1,10}|(?!.{12})\d+.\d+)$

This regex allows me to take decimals 

but my requirement is it should allow 2 Decimal places after number.

kindly help

Comment: ^([1-9]|[1-9]\\d|100)$ this regex allows number 1-100 but i need it should allow 1-210

Comment: Please post a new question if you need help with another situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use a logical OR operator `|` to combine two regexes.

```
^(?:[0-9]{12}|[0-9]{14})$
```

It matches exactly 12 or 14 digits.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fQ6sV3/7)

Answer (score 0):

`^[0-9]{12}$|^[0-9]{14}$`.... witness:

```
public static String getMatches(String text, String regexp) {
    return new Boolean(text.matches(regexp)).toString();
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.err.println(getMatches("111111111111")); // string of 12, prints "true"
    System.err.println(getMatches("111111")); // string of 6, prints "false"
    System.err.println(getMatches("1111111111111")); // string of 13, prints "false"
    System.err.println(getMatches("11111111111111")); // string of 14, prints "true"
}
```